# Converting a single dictionary value from string to integer?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, int

Let us consider

```
set = {'a': '98', 'b': '10', 'c': 'nike', 'd': 'paarudas', 'e': '3'}
```

I want to change it as,

```
set = {'a': **98**, 'b': **10**, 'c': 'nike', 'd': 'paarudas', 'e': **3**}.
```

and one more doubt if i get

```
set_1 = {'a': '98', 'b': '10', 'c': 'nike', 'd': 'paarudas', 'e': ''}
```

Then i have to change it to

```
set_1 = {'a': **98**, 'b': **10**, 'c': 'nike', 'd': 'paarudas', 'e': ''}.
```

Comment: What do you mean by `**` in your code?

Comment: It's supposed to be bold

Comment: How do you build those dictionaries? You should probably do the conversion back there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ python3
>>> s = {'a': '98', 'b': '10', 'c': 'nike', 'd': 'paarudas', 'e': '3'}
>>> {k:int(v) if v.isdigit() else v for k,v in s.items()}
{'a': 98, 'c': 'nike', 'b': 10, 'e': 3, 'd': 'paarudas'}
```

Comment: It would be (slightly) better to use `for x,y in s.items()` than doing three lookups for each key. Also, it might be more readable as a dict comprehension: `{x: int(y) if y.isdigit() else y for x, y in s.items()}`.

Comment: @lvc Your solution is much better. Thanks

Comment: Worked in my case

Answer (score 4):

```
def int_if_possible(value):
    try: return int(value)
    except: return value

result = dict((k, int_if_possible(v)) for (k, v) in original.items())
```

Please do not call your variable `set`; that is another data type (like `dict`).